# Set Background Color of specific CollectionView Cells according to IndexPath

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm pretty new to Swift and programming in general, so sorry for the simple question:

I want to develop a calendar that uses an (horizontally scrollable) `UICollectionView` as interface. Every cell of the `UICollectionView` is supposed to have a label with the number of the respective day and the weekday.

For this purpose I have an `dateArray` that stores the date-objects. The `setupCell`- method is putting the respective data onto the labels of the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Cells that show Sundays should be highlighted by having a different background-color than the other cells.

I tried to implement this functionality in the `cellForItemAt` - method, but got stuck there.

My function looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        

        let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let weekdayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        weekdayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE"

        cell.setupCell(day: dayFormatter.string(from: dateArray[indexPath.item]), weekday: weekdayFormatter.string(from: dateArray[indexPath.item]))

    
        
        if Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: dateArray[indexPath.item]) == 1   {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }

        
        return cell
    }
```

With this function the Sundays are highlighted as planned, but only as long as I don't scroll. After some scrolling at the end all cells will be highlighted.

I'm thankful for every hint to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UICollectionViewCell`s are being *reused*. Hence the name `dequeueReusableCell`. This means that, for example, the cell at index `0` is the same cell as at index `30`. When you have set the color of the cell at index `0` to `UIColor.gray`, the cell at `30` will also be gray, unless you set it to another color. Because all cells are going to be reused, and all cells will eventually be a "Sunday" at some point, they will all become colored.

There is an easy fix for this, do not only set a color for the ones you want to have a color but also do the opposite.

For example:

```swift
if Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: dateArray[indexPath.item]) == 1 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

I haven't tried it myself before, but there seems to be another way to achieve this as well. You could also implement the `prepareForReuse()` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)) method in the `UICollectionViewCell` itself. You could do this by adding the following to the cell:

```swift
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Or set to another color you want
}
```

Another method would be to set the `backgroundColor` in the `setupCell()` you created for your cell. This will be called every time a cell is reused, so this might be an excellent place to do this as well. Just apply the same logic as above (if Sunday -> gray, else -> white).

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer + explanation!